# hard drive broken?

Tags: linux, hard-drive

One day, the 500 GB SATA Western Digital EXT4 hard drive was no longer detected by the BIOS. So I used a USB cable and connected the drive to the USB port. After following a few tutorials I got this using root. Anybody can help ?

dmesg

```
[ 2797.127391] usb 1-5: USB disconnect, address 7
[ 2816.396052] usb 1-5: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 8
[ 2816.529972] usb 1-5: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=2338
[ 2816.529978] usb 1-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=5
[ 2816.529983] usb 1-5: Product: USB to ATA/ATAPI Bridge
[ 2816.529987] usb 1-5: Manufacturer: JMicron
[ 2816.529991] usb 1-5: SerialNumber: 152D203380B6
[ 2816.530212] usb 1-5: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
[ 2816.531507] scsi7 : SCSI emulation for USB Mass Storage devices
[ 2816.531848] usb-storage: device found at 8
[ 2816.531852] usb-storage: waiting for device to settle before scanning
[ 2821.528354] usb-storage: device scan complete
[ 2821.529139] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access                                    PQ: 0 ANSI: 2 CCS
[ 2821.530275] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg7 type 0
[ 2821.533631] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdg] Attached SCSI disk
```

dumpe2fs /dev/sdg

```
dumpe2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
dumpe2fs: Invalid argument while trying to open /dev/sdg
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

dumpe2fs /dev/sdg1

```
dumpe2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
dumpe2fs: No such file or directory while trying to open /dev/sdg1
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

fsck.ext4 /dev/sdg

```
e2fsck 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
fsck.ext4: Invalid argument while trying to open /dev/sdg

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a correct ext2
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193
```

fsck.ext4 /dev/sdg1

```
e2fsck 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
fsck.ext4: No such file or directory while trying to open /dev/sdg1

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a correct ext2
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193
```

mount -t ext4 /dev/sdg /mnt/debian

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdg,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       (could this be the IDE device where you in fact use
       ide-scsi so that sr0 or sda or so is needed?)
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

mount -t ext4 /dev/sdg1 /mnt/debian

```
mount: special device /dev/sdg1 does not exist
```

mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdg

```
mke2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
/dev/sdg is entire device, not just one partition!
Proceed anyway? (y,n) y
mkfs.ext4: Device size reported to be zero.  Invalid partition specified, or
    partition table wasn't reread after running fdisk, due to
    a modified partition being busy and in use.  You may need to reboot
    to re-read your partition table.
```

**EDIT**
file -s /dev/sdg

```
/dev/sdg: empty
```

Comment: `file -s /dev/sdg`.

Comment: fdisk -l /dev/sdg

Comment: @CarlF The command does not return any output at all.

Comment: I have the exact same problem, and looking for a way to restore the drive contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193
```

Did you try running the quoted command? I've had good luck (about 80% success) trying that in the past.

Before anyhing else: you did use DD (or your preferred tool) to make an image of the drive, right?

Comment: The quoted command returns the same exact output as mentioned in my question. At this point, the data is not important and I just want to reformat the disk but apparently I cannot manage either.

Comment: You might check whether Western Digital has a low-level diagnostic program for this drive, but you're right, it seems as if the drive is toast. Luckily a replacement will cost you $50 for twice the capacity.

Comment: I booted to Windows and downloaded the Western Digital drive check program and it did not detect it. So, I think it is safe to say the drive is broken.